# Excluding quotes in a split method Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use regexp in a split method in ruby.

I have the string:

```
"Mark Sally 'John Smith' Steve"
```

and I am trying to get the array:

```
 ["Mark", "Sally", "John Smith", "Steve"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `split`ting the string, I would consider matching or using a parser for this.

```
s = "Mark Sally 'John Smith' Steve"
p s.scan(/'([^']+)'|(\S+)/).flatten.compact
#=> ["Mark", "Sally", "John Smith", "Steve"]
```

Comment: this is perfect. Do you know how I would be able to exclude single quotes OR double quotes?

Comment: `/'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)"|(\S+)/`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for CSV reader - it specifically handles multiple words grouped together by quotes.

```
require 'csv'

line = "Mark Sally 'John Smith' Steve"
line.parse_csv(:col_sep => " ", :quote_char => "'")
puts line  # ["Mark", "Sally", "John Smith", "Steve"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you `scan` rather than `split`:

```
r = /
    (?<=') # match a single quote in a positive lookbehind
    .*?    # match any number of any characters, lazily
    (?=')  #match a single quote in a positive lookahead
    |   # or
    \w+ # match one or more word characters
    /x

"Mark Sally 'John Smith' Steve".scan(r)
   #=> ["Mark", "Sally", "John Smith", "Steve"]
```

Note that order is important here:

```
r = /\w+|(?<=').*?(?=')/
"Mark Sally 'John Smith' Steve".scan(r)
   #=> ["Mark", "Sally", "John", "Smith", "Steve"]
```